Three-way diff between three git versions in IntelliJ
Does IntelliJ provide three-way diff natively (ie. without an external merge tool being configured)?
The docs have plenty of references, but none of them actually pan out:

Seems available only if the file you want to diff has changes: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html
Only if you have configured the IDE as your Git merge tool of choice and you have a merge conflict: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-use-idea-as-default-command-line-merge-tool.html#resolve-merge-conflicts-in-ij


Is "yes, as you have shown" not the answer you are looking for? Why not?

It seems that this is the best I can hope for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44535594/148680 though I've yet to test the script out.
